# Setting up GitWebLinks extension in VS/vscode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

The extension I am talking about can be found in these two links:

1. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=reduckted.GitWebLinks
2. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=reduckted.vscode-gitweblinks

This extension enables you to create hyperlinks from the editor to your git file/selection on the server.

There is specified that the extension provides support for **Azure Dev Ops**. It should be straight forward, but maybe there is something that I am missing in the setup.

From **vscode** when I try to use the commands:

- Git Web Links: Copy Web Link to Section
- Git Web Links: Copy Web Link to File

I am getting the error **This workspace is not tracked by Git** (and I am pretty sure that I am tracking the workspace by Git).

Is there any configuration that I need to set in order to make it work for **Azure Dev Ops**? Did anyone else faced the same issue with this extension?

#### UPDATE

These extensions work now! No extra configuration was needed. Probably some of the releases after this post was posted resolved the issue.